# Prove $(A\times B)^C \sim A^C\times B^C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let A,B,C be sets. Prove $(A\times B)^C \sim A^C\times B^C$

In order to prove it, we need to define a function and show:

1. The function is **to** range of defined function.
2. The function is injective.
3. The function is surjective.

My question is **only** regarding the first step.

Proof of first step:

We define a function $H: A^C\times B^C \to (A\times B)^C$ with the following rule: $\forall(f,g)\in A^C\times B^C$, $H((f,g))$ is a function from $C$ to $A\times B$ which defined by the following rule: $\forall x\in C, (H(f,g))(x)=(f(x),g(x))$.

Let be an arbitrary element $p\in Img(H)$, we need to show $p\in (A\times B)^C$ to complete this part of the proof. $p\in Img(H)$ then exist $m\in A^C\times B^C$ such that $H(m)=p$.

My difficult is to show formally the first step, I mean, we need to show $Img(H)\subseteq (A\times B)^C$ and since it is very clear, I found a difficulty to formalize it.

---

While defining the function above, I have tried a lot to define the function H when the domain is the $(A\times B)^C$ and the range is $A^C\times B^C$ bijective. However, I did not succeed write it formally, so I will be glad to see the if it could be defined formally. (Where the issue? $\forall g\in (A\times B)^C$, $H(g)=(g^{-1}\cap A\times A,g^{-1}\cap B\times B)$ How can I be sure that $g$ is inverse(bijective) when I define it, is it fine or I need first to show that is bijective so $g$ is inverse?)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I do not familiar with thinking of the map, I am learning from "How to prove it by Daniel J. Valleman" and I don`t see this terms in this book. Could you tell what the professional term of maps or give a reference to read about it? 
However, if we not thinking in this terms currently, is it possible to write it formally in my way?

Comment: You are defining $H((f,g))$ explicitly; you are saying it has domain $C$. Now, to verify that the image of $H((f,g))$ is in $A\times B$, you just need to invoke the fact that since $f\in A^C$, then $f(x)\in A$, and since $g\in B^C$, then $g(x)\in B$; therefore, $(f(x),g(x))\in A\times B$, as required.

Comment: To verfiy that $H$ is surjective, given $h\in (A\times B)^C$, define $f=\pi_A\circ h$ and $g=\pi_B\circ h$. Verify that $H((f,g))=h$ by verifying they have the same values at each $x\in C$.

Comment: Your definition of $H(g)$ doesn't work, because you don't know anything about $g$ other than that it is a function from $C$ to $A\times B$. $g^{-1}$ need not make any sense, and if you view $g$ is a set of ordered pairs and $g^{-1}$ as the reversal, note that $g\subseteq C\times (A\times B)$, so the intersection of $g^{-1}$ with $A\times A$ is empty. In short, you have a whole bunch of symbols in there, but they don't mean anything.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I will rethink regarding definition of H(g). Regarding your first comment, you have showed that $H((f,g))$ is function **to** $A\times B$, but we need to show $H$ is function to $(A\times B)^C$, am I wrong?

Comment: Well, if  $H(f,g)$ is a function with domain $C$ and range $A\times B$, then it is an element of $(A\times B)^C$.... If this happens for each $(f,g)$ in the domain of $H$, then $H$ is a function with codomain $(A\times B)^C$. What is the issue?